# calculate the difference between two dates and time on excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between two dates and time and the result should be on "hh:mm:ss"

```
   |           E          |           F         |    G     |
===+======================+=====================+==========+
3  | 01/01/2013  13:34:50 | 31/01/2013  7:34:05 | 17:59:15 |
```

I tried this `=TEXT(F3-E3;"hh:mm:ss")` but it only count the difference from times, not date. I also tried to add `dd` like this: `=TEXT(F3-E3;"dd hh:mm:ss")` It works, but that's not the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Is the second date January 10th or October 1st  ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
=TEXT(F3-E3;"[h]:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the semicolon should be replaced with a comma:

```
=TEXT(E5-D5,"[h]:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Some country's versions of Excel use a semicolon instead of the comma use in the US version. Since the OP used one, I'm guessing that's true for their version.